# $ax=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $x=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Prove that $ax=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $a=0$ $\lor$ $x=0$, where $a$ is a scalar from a field and $x$ is an element of the vector space on this field.

I would like a hint or maybe a solution to prove this theorem by using vector space axioms. Can you explain if there is a difference in the proof of this theorem if we use abstract algebra without the need of vector space axioms but only by using group theory knowledge.

Comment: Since you're in a vector space and are using multiplication by scalars, group theory tells you nothing.

Comment: Hint: if $a\neq0$, then $x=a^{-1}ax$. The theorem fails to be true for Abelian groups. Consider $M=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, and find a characterization of $ax=0$.

Comment: $0 = 0.\vec{v},$ or $0 = \lambda. \vec{0}.$

Comment: thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Hint: If $x\neq0\implies x+ax=x\implies(1+a)x=x\implies1+a=1\implies a=0$