# Proof that if $ax = 0_v$ either a = 0 or x = 0

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand it is similar to question ([$ax=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $x=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652157/ax-0-if-and-only-if-a-0-or-x-0)) but i haven't yet defined vector devision so is there an alternative way to solve that if $ax=0$,a=0 or x=0_v$ (I can prove alternative). I can prove x=0 but can't see how a=0 is possible?

($a$ is scalar, $v$ is vector)

$ax = 0_v$

Comment: If $a=0$, done. If $a\neq 0$ then....

Comment: Those other questions don't use vector division. I'm not sure vector division is allowed unless your structure is something more, like an algebra over a field

Comment: It is identical to the question you linked. Also, division by a vector is undefined.

Comment: It's not *vector* division you need; it's *scalar* division.  And since the scalars form a field where multiplicative inverses exist, you have scalar division.

Comment: I can't see how obtaining a=0 is trivial. As the we're proving from left to right?

Comment: A couple things:  first remember to surround your mathematical expressions (and variables) with \$ signs when you post so that it renders with Mathjax.  You can trigger subscript with underscores, e.g. 0_v becomes $0_v$.

Comment: Second, it's not that $a= 0$ is 'trivial', exactly...
The logic is as follows:
we want to show $ax = 0$ implies $a = 0$ or $x = 0$.  
We divide the proof into cases.  $a$ can be only one of two things, $0$ or nonzero.  In the first case $a = 0$, so we have nothing to prove.  In the second case $a$ is not $0$ so we can divide the equation $ax= 0$ by $a$ on both sides to see $x = \frac{0}{a} = 0$.

Comment: I can see the logic and it feels very intuitive, however as we're proving from left to right, in the case a=0 we've gone essentially from right to left which doesn't seem like the proof holds? As in we've just said a=0?

Answer (score 3):

If $a=0$, then you have nothing to do. If $a\neq 0$, then you have $a^{-1}$, so:
$$ax=0 \Rightarrow a^{-1}ax=a^{-1}\cdot0=0 \Rightarrow x=0$$

Comment: we don't know that inverses exist yet.

Comment: every scalar $a\neq 0$ has inverse, since the set of scalars always is a field (e.g., real numbers, complex numbers...)

Answer (score 0):

There's no "vector division" in a vector space. The matter is not to show directly that $x \neq 0_{v} \implies a=0$, but rather to show the contraposate $a \neq 0 \implies x=0_{v}$, which is easy since you can use the scalar inverse $a^{-1}$ of $a$.